# How to apply a real time constraint on a moving gear

Tags: parent

Here are some examples of what I have already accomplished

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryuK2.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ful4K.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuPCH.jpg

The next gif is where I run into a problem. Right after the ball hits the 'slider.' I can move the bone, but I can't move the entire selection, as seen in the previous gifs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO19V.jpg

Now that you've seen the basic idea, and the main problem. I will now show you a  less complicated version of my end result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPifE.jpg

I want the gear inside the lever to spin freely on the grounded gear in real time. I wanted this so in the long run, I don't have to animate the gear placement when at a certain point. Speeding up the process of my work flow.

My example file
[image]

My Lever Project file.
[image]

Comment: for the spinning effect, using either a Transformation Constraint or a driver would work just the same, and have the bonus of not forcing your to use physics at all. Would this be a viable solution for you? Or are there other reasons that force you going for simulation?

Comment: I thought I made this clear when I said "Real Time" animation. I don't want anything to spin or change without me having to handle the object. I want everything to move in result of other objects. "Say an animated character grabbed the handle and pulled it down. His hand moves the lever, and the teeth move the gear while the lever moves.

Comment: Both Constraints and Drivers would do exactly that. You would only need to pull The handle

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what I am trying to do. Because what you are imposing is basically cheating.

Comment: There's an old animation adage:  "Don't make it if you can fake it."  Do not try to do things a complicated way when it is easier to do something simpler that still works.

Comment: If this is for animation (even in a game) a driver would be least elaborate and most suitable. You would only have the lever control, it would be easy for an animator to handle and would work without playing back / calculating ALL the frames; a big drawback of the simulation.

Comment: Leander, I've tried that before. The driver stays in on place, it doesn't go around the gear. It just bugs out in one place eventually popping of the constraint even with all the necessary precautions have been placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're interested in this solution, as it does not deal with physics simulation but using traditional constraints instead. As mentioned in a few comments already, this is recommended for various reasons, like easier handling and setup, better stability, etc. For what you're really trying to achieve, this will work.

Here is the file rigged based on your provided Blend:

[image]

I'm using an Armature, parenting a few bones in there in a hierachy like this:

[image: hierachy]

Main Bone and Lever Bone are purely for better flexibility later on when animating. Using the Main Bone you can relocate the whole rig, the gear bone allows additional offset. Both bones are optional, but recommended. The lever bone is a child of the Gear Bone, so it follows the movement of that, and the sprocket bone a child of the lever bone.

The rig itself looks like this:

[image: rig]

I turned on Axis Display for each bone, so you can see the local bone axis and better understand why I set certain values later on in the Constraint. Speaking of the Constraint, I used a Transformation constraint to achieve the desired effect:

[image: constraint]

The logic is: If you rotate the lever bone by 8 degrees along the Z axis, the sprocket bone has to spin 36 degrees along the Y axis, but in the opposite direction, hence the -36 degrees. Where I got these values from? Simply count the number of teeth of gear and sprocket. The **Extrapolate** option makes sure that this math relationship is kept even if you exceed the values.

Now, if you rotate the red lever bone, the sprocket spins around the gear.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond. I thought this one was a lost cause. Thinking it was so complicated. Right now it's too late for me. I'll check this out tomorrow. Thank you for your time, and have a nice day.

Comment: This isn't quite the answer I was looking for, but it's another option I can live with until I find another option. When you said "transformation constraint" I thought you were talking about something else. Sorry I so brash in the comments. I've wasted about a month of my time trying to figure this out. And I was pretty much at my limits end.

Comment: One Question. Why does the sprockets transformation locks, all locked. How exactly does the gear rotate and transform when it's transformation locks says it shouldn't do that.

Comment: Alright Two Questions. How the heck did you get the Sprocket Green without a bone group color, or a texture.

Comment: @JaredWolf Both questions are targeting the bones, not the objects I suppose. Regarding the transformations, Constraints are allowed to manipulate transform channels regardless of the locking state. If you want to further limit constraints in regards to channels, there is the Limit Rotation, Limit Location etc. constraints to achieve this. The locks in the transform panel have the purpose to stop the user from accidentally moving the bones out of place. Since the sprocket is completely controlled by the lever, I decided to cut off any user interaction, and thus locked the channels.

Comment: @JaredWolf regarding the green color, that's a theme / Blender convention. If a bone has a constraint, it is colored in green (or yellow in case of the IK constraint), so the rigger knows about the existance of constraints on a bone. For the lever bone I used Bone Groups to colorize it, but this you figured yourself already anyways.